# Convert nested hash of array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I convert an array in nested hash in ruby

For example:
From

```
    {
       "errors": {
           "name": [
               "must be filled"
           ],
           "type": [
               "must be filled"
           ],
           "address": {
               "country_id": [
                   "must be filled"
               ]
           },
           "group": {
               "name": [
                   "is missing"
               ]
           },
           "contacts": {
               "2": {
                   "name": [
                       "must be filled"
                   ],
                   "phone": {
                       "0": {
                           "number": [
                               "must be filled"
                           ],
                           "email": [
                             "must be valid"
                           ]
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

To

```
   {
       "errors": {
           "name": "must be filled",
           "type": "must be filled",
           "address": {
               "country_id": "must be filled"
           },
           "group": {
               "name": "is missing"
           },
           "contacts": [
             {
               "name": "must be filled",
               "index": 2,
               "phone": [
                 {
                   "number": "must be filled",
                   "email": "must be valid",
                   "index": 0
                 }
               ]
           }
       }
   }
```

I want remove key of hash ("2", "0") and convert it to hash of array. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this ?

Comment: Please define your requirements and show what have you already tried. For now the most simple answer to your question would be "edit it by hand".

Comment: Just update question. Thanks.

Comment: you have an unclosed bracket in there. I'm assuming it should be the third to last character?

Answer (score 0):

I tried and succeeded in the following way. Thanks all

```
def change(messages)
      result = {}
      array = []
      messages.each do |field, message|
        if message.is_a?(Hash)

          if field.is_a? Integer
            value = change(message)
            array.push(value.merge(index: field))
            result = array
          else
            value = change(message)
            result[field] = value
          end

        else
          result[field] = message.at(0)

        end
      end

      result
    end
```